# Different FlatList on bigger screen

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I want to have this same style FlatList on small and big device.

In smaller screen I have perfectly white color between a item within this List, but on the bigger device, I don't see this white color.

How to fix it ?

my FlatList

```
const placeList = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.listContainer}
            data={props.placesList}
            renderItem={(info) => (
                <ListItem
                    placeName={info.item.name}
                    placeImage={info.item.image}
                    onItemPressed={() => 
                      props.onItemSelected(info.item.key)}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listContainer: {
        width: "100%",
    }
});
```

and here my ListItem

```
const listItem = (props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onItemPressed}>
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Image 
               resizeMode="contain" 
               source={props.placeImage} 
               style={styles.placeImage}
            />
            <Text>{props.placeName}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listItem: {
        width: "100%",
        marginBottom: 5,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    placeImage: {
        marginRight: 8,
        height: 30,
        width: 30
    }
});
```

This is how it looks (5,10' vs 7') :

[click 5,10' size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZbT7.png)
[image]

[click 7,0' size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhTl2.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try dimension props like `width:dimension.get('screen or window ').Width` you can use same property for height just change props height or width and
U can also add `width:dimension.get('screen or window ').Width/2` like this.. U can customize that and that view can be adjust itself on different screens....